# Get mean value / std of bar plot matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

[image: My plot]

I have a bar plot that I want to get the mean of. I tried creating a dictionary that acts as a "function" for the Stroke Counts (x) and the relative frequencies:

```
fx_temp = df.iloc[:, [0,3]].copy()
fx = list(zip(fx_temp["Stroke Count"],fx_temp["Relative Frequency"]))
fx
[(8, 11.762452145035647),
 (6, 9.873249013337801),
...
```

The df is structured as follows:

```
  Stroke Count  Most Common Char    Total Frequency Relative Frequency
2       8              物               2387272         11.762452
1       6              字               2003845      9.873249
13      9              音               1812762      8.931754
6       5              用               1697177      8.362249
10      10             家               1604956      7.907862
...
```

Code for graph generation:

```
x = df["Stroke Count"]
y = df["Relative Frequency"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
rects = ax.bar(x = x,height = y,color = my_colors,width = 0.8,tick_label=x)
ax.tick_params(labelrotation=45)
ax.set_ylabel("Relative Frequency (%)")
ax.set_xlabel("Stroke Count (int)")
ax.set_title("Stroke Counts and Relative Frequency")

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(d[height]),
                        xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                        xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                        textcoords="offset points",
                        ha='center', va='bottom')
autolabel(rects)
plt.margins(0.05, 0.2)
```

Please let me know if there is any other information needed. I have also tried .mean() on x and y. By "Eye-balling" the image, I think the mean should be around 8-9 ish. However I could not get a value near that. I would also like to get the standard deviation from this distribution.

Comment: Are you looking for the mean stroke count or mean frequency?

Comment: What I want is the mean of a discrete distribution, where x = stroke counts and fx = frequencies. I know how to calculate the mean for such a distribution in general, which should be something like sigma(x * fx) / len(x), but I was wondering if there was a better more pandas / matplotlib way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find the mean and standard deviation of the histogram.  If you had the raw data, where each word was represented by a row and a Stroke Count, you could do this by:

```
df['Stroke Count'].mean()
```

and

```
df['Stroke Count'].std()
```

However instead you have an aggregate table that works great for plotting histograms, but is less intuitive for calculating stats.  This can still be done by weighting each bar/category, adding them up and finding the mean.

```
total_strokes = df['Stroke Count'].multiply(df['Total Frequency'], axis=0).sum()
total_words = df['Total Frequency'].sum()
average_strokes = 1.*total_strokes / total_words
```

To calculate the standard deviation, you can do it the old fashioned way by literally calculating the square root of the average variance from the mean.

```
sum_of_squares = (df['Stroke Count'] - average_strokes).pow(2).multiply(df['Total Frequency'], axis=0).sum()
standard_deviation = (sum_of_squares  / total_words)**0.5
```

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you - I was unsure how to apply the formula with a df, but this seems to work well.

Comment: So the "sum_of_squares" is returning a Series - should I add up all of these values in the series and then get the standard deviation by dividing the sum by total_words and taking the square root?

Comment: sum_of_squares returns a value which is equal to the sum of each value's squared difference from the mean.  We can find the average difference by dividing this number by total_words.  To get standard deviation, we then take the square root of this value.